# dup flag not available in libmosquitto

Tags: c, mqtt, mosquitto, libmosquitto

I was working on a code using libmosquitto v3.1.x and I couldn't find a method to capture the dup flag of a message.

Nb1: From my understanding dup flag indicates that the message was already send but was not acknowledged by recipient.

Nb2: I was referring https://mosquitto.org/api/files/mosquitto-h.html
for libmosquitto API descriptions.

Comment: Yep, looks right. You should probably be using the [Paho c](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/c/index.php) these days anyway which [does have support](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/mqttdoc/MQTTClient/html/struct_m_q_t_t_client__message.html#adc4cf3f551bb367858644559d69cfdf5)

Comment: oh that's sad news for me, Is there some workaround for doing it, like a hack of any sort.

Comment: Use the Paho library...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At time of writing of this answer dup flag functionality is not supported by libmosquitto (v1.04.15).

Its better to use an advanced library like [Paho](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/c/index.php) if you are working ony anything serious.